# TFS to VSTS Migration error: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

I am working on migrating our on premise TFS system to VSTS but I am getting a rather generic error that does not give me much to go on. I did not find anything related in the troubleshooting guide

[Error] TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: c47a7fd7-2b13-4d47-8aa8-00a7b09367ca

See our documentation for assistance: https://aka.ms/VSTSMigrationTroubleshooting

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DataImport.WebApi.InvalidDataImportRequestException: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: c47a7fd7-2b13-4d47-8aa8-00a7b09367ca.
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__48.MoveNext()
...

Some details:

- The data source is a SQL Server instance hosted in Azure since one table in the collection is larger than recommended for doing a DACPAC import.
- This a DryRun import
- I am using AAD credentials to create the account on our corporate tenant.
- I manually created a test VSTS account to make sure it was not a permission issue.

#### Update

I re-ran the prepare process but opted out of including Release Management and Package Management. Since we are on TFS 2017 Update 3 these are in 'Preview' and TFSMigrator asks to include them or not. I was able to successfully perform an import to VSTS with that configuration. We do use Release Management extensively so I need to get that working. My current theory is that our Networking and Security teams did not give all the VSTS IP addresses needed access to the SQL VM.

Note: Our networking team has verified that the documented IP addresses are not blocked in our firewall.

Comment: Which version of TFS on premise and SQL you are running? Which versions you are using in Azure?

Comment: Tfs 2017 update 3 and sql server 2014 on premise. Sql server 2016 on the Azure VM.

Comment: @Tony Do you mean you have found the root cause of your issue?

Comment: We have determined that it is related to the Release Management / Package Management part of the import but we do not know what is causing the issue. Our networking team says that all the VSTS IP addresses listed for the central US region are white listed in our firewall that is in front of the SQL VM.